# phyper: why are upper.tail and 1 - lower.tail different? (fisher exact test for over representation)

Tags: r

A Fisher exact test is often used for over representation analysis of gene lists in a pathway. Consider the following example of a contingency table:

```
              in pathway
                 Y   N
in gene list  Y 90  110  |  200 
              N 10  790  |  800
              ------------------
               100  900  | 1000
```

There are essentially two ways to do a Fisher test based over representation analysis in R. 
The first is to use fisher.test (which takes the contingency matrix as input)

```
fisher.test(matrix(c(90,10,110,790), nrow = 2), alternative = 'greater')$p.value
[1] 1.486473e-59
```

The second is to use phyper ([Meng's notes give an excellent explanation on how to use phyper, including why the "-1", and what q, m, n, k exactly mean](http://mengnote.blogspot.qa/2012/12/calculate-correct-hypergeometric-p.html)):

```
phyper(q=90-1, m=100, n=900, k=200, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 1.486473e-59
```

My question: why does this differ from:

```
1 - phyper(q=90-1, m=100, n=900, k=200, lower.tail = TRUE)
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C-level code for [`phyper`](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/phyper.c) avoids some calculations (which cause [floating point numerical errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)), and hence is more accurate, when you specifically ask for the tail that you are interested in.